# I want to disable mouse scroll trigger in fullpage.js only

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, fullpage.js

I know that this issue can be resolved by just setting autoScrolling: false.
But the problem is that when scrolling and just stopping somewhere on the page after a couple of seconds of waiting it gets me to the top of a certain section.

I would appreciate it if someone helps me with this.

Here is my code below

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <full-page ref="fullpage" :options="options">
      <div class="section">
        <button class="next" @click="$refs.fullpage.api.moveSectionDown()">Next</button>
        Section 1
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <button class="prev" @click="$refs.fullpage.api.moveSectionUp()">Prev</button>
        Section 2
      </div>

      <div class="section">
        Section 3
      </div>

      <div class="section">
        Section 4
      </div>
    </full-page>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'fullSection',
  data () {
    return {
      options: {
        menu: '#menu',
        anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
        sectionsColor: ['#41b883', '#ff5f45', '#0798ec'],
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'right',
        navigationTooltips: [],
        showActiveTooltip: true,
        slidesNavigation: true,
        scrollBar: true,
        autoScrolling: false,
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the problem is that when scrolling and just stopping somewhere on the page after a couple of seconds of waiting it gets me to the top of a certain section.

You can disable this by using the fullPaeg.js option `fitToSection: false`.